# polymorphism with abstract class on cout

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, operator-overloading

i have abstract class (class "father") and son class

i want to write on the father the operator << and implemnt it on the son

here the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class father {
    virtual friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & out, father &obj) = 0;

};

class son: public father  {
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & out, son &obj)
    {
        out << "bla bla";
        return out;
    }
};
void main()
{
    son obj;
    cout << obj;

}
```

i get 3 error

Error   3   error C2852 : 'operator <<' : only data members can be initialized within a class

Error   2   error C2575 : 'operator <<' : only member functions and bases can be virtual

Error   1   error C2254 : '<<' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier not allowed on friend function

what i can do please?

Comment: Global functions cannot be pure virtual.

Comment: so what can i do if i want on the header write the "<<" ??
you know  , the header include all the "header of the function" that i want to omplement on the son....

Comment: You might provide a `protected` pure virtual function `std::ostream& put(std::ostream& os) const = 0;` and a global function `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & out, father &obj)` utilizing it. Note that `friend ` relationships aren't inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot make an operator `virtual`, you can make them *call* a regular virtual function, like this:

```
class father {
    virtual ostream& format(ostream & out, father &obj) = 0;
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & out, father &obj) {
        return format(out, obj);
    }
};

class son: public father  {
    virtual ostream& format(ostream & out, son &obj) {
        out << "bla bla";
        return out;
    }
};
```

There is only one `operator <<` now, but each subclass of `father` can provide its own implementation by overriding the virtual member function `format`.